# MSSQLServer2008 R2\Instance, Only 4 Why?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Heard that the new R2 only supports 4 Instances. Who can explain us this restriction in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have read Enterprise edition will support up to 25 instances.  The reason for the restrictions is they are now releasing a Datacenter edition.  So if you want more then 25 instances you will have to invest in the much more expensive datacenter edition instead.  I wouldn't count on SA giving you a free pass to R2 Datacenter from R1 Enterprise either.

I don't know Microsoft's official reasons but they are probably saying this is to match licensing/editions more closely with the Windows Server offerings, but IMHO it just seems like a big money grab to me.

Comment: Personmally I do not see the money grab. Usabe of multiple instances has significant administrative issues. THere are VERY few scenarios where mutiple instances IMHO make any sense given that ONE instance can load unlimited databases anyway.

Comment: Very true, this change is not going to affect a lot of people.  But I still think it is a money grab, as they are taking features away from one product, only to make them available in a new and more expensive product.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft happily competed with Oracle etc on price, but now you're tied into using their systems, they've realised they can up the pricing and you'll pay more.

They are a business, there to make money for the company, not to give you lots of free stuff.